# loading different pages for different users

Tags: php, model-view-controller, session, authentication

I have different users for my PHP web application. I have completed the implementation for one of the users. I want to know how to create "different views" according to the user who is logged in.

Should I create a directory as such?

```
/root/student/
/root/admin/
/root/admin
```

But with this approach, there's going to be a lot of duplicating content.

Is there any general approach to this?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to achieve? How different is the content from user to user? Usually admin panel is separate so yoursite.com/admin while the rest of the users get the same view but certain elements maybe hidden/shown depending on privileges.

Comment: @alec I have two users, student and advisor. student can only view meetings and advisor can create/view. I have the usr_level variable as well. Should I use if/else statements to control which user gets to see what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use templates for the front-end code generation not to duplicate the code.

There is no need to create directories. Human readable URLs parsing method depends mostly on the web server you use. In Apache look at `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: i am already using index.php and passing the page through get

Comment: If the issue is not in the URL parsing, then I don't see the issue.
You should have a set of views and assign appropriate view from the controller.
If some views contain a lot of duplicate code make them inheritable from parent views or split into blocks and include that blocks into the end view.

Answer (score 1):

When usser has logged in you need create Session variable "user_type" or some other. Now you just need to edit php page and insert if clause -

```
if(user_type == "admin"){
$getcontent->adminInfo();
}else {
$getcontent->userInfo();
}
```

adminInfo and userInfo are functions that return array...
Like Minras say, duplicate pages for each users is not acceptable:) You can use session variables to identificate users and when give them info:)